# Switch dominant tag for synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I was looking at the [list of all tag synonyms](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) and checking out which requests were pending. I noticed that [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff), with 68 questions, is proposed as a synonym for [redundancy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy), which has 31 questions. This would mean that any questions tagged [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff) would automatically be changed to [redundancy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy). The term "layoff" is clearly more common, and I think the two should be reversed.

Is there a good way to get these synonyms switched so that [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff) is the primary tag?

The only suggestion I have is to downvote the current proposed synonym and instead propose the opposite synonym. Unfortunately I don't have the rep to do that, so I have to ask for someone else to do it instead.

<sub>*PS, while you're on the synonym page, please vote for any pending ones that you agree with!*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The [breakout](https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/974442/count-questions-tagged-with-a-given-tag-combination) between [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff) / [redundancy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy) for questions tagged [united-kingdom](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom) is currently 3/12, while for questions tagged [united-states](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) it is 5/0.

On the other hand, questions tagged [germany](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) use [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff) as well (2 questions), not [redundancy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy). There are no questions about layoff/redundancy related to other European countries or [europe](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe).

While the numbers are not very statistically sound to draw conclusions, [redundancy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy) looks like the UK term, and [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff) like an international one. On this basis, I would argue that [layoff](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layoff) is a better term for international use.

Comment: Fr guy, never heard about redundancy here.

Answer (score 4):

Layoff is the US term, redundancy the European/UK one. I'm not sure what the breakdown of user locations is, but that should probably be taken into consideration along with number of posts?

Comment: I know there are often complaints that SE is too US-centric and doesn't consider other countries enough, so I would guess that there are far more US users than UK. There are currently 899 questions tagged [tag:united-states] and 599 tagged [tag:united-kingdom], and I know a lot of US questions are usually tagged with the state but not the country.